# Text positioning

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles getting the text to position as I would like it to. The following is my code.

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="h1">
        <div class="left"><span class="font">H</span>ello</div>
        <div class="left"><span class="font">T</span>here</div>
        <div class="left"><span class="font">J</span>ames</div>
</h1>
```

and my **CSS**

```
.h1 {
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    font-size:20px;
}
.font {
    font-size:35px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

That all works great but when I try add another class to the div the next word goes down a line. Here is the code I am trying to get to work, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rampill/qTguq/2/). I am trying to get the words to be like a stepping stone, if you have suggestions on how I could do that in a simpler way then that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qTguq/3/

Remove the `,` s on multiple class assignments. Multiple class names should be `space` separated.

```
<h1 class="h1">
        <div class="left"><span class="font">H</span>ello</div>
        <div class="left down"><span class="font">T</span>here</div>
        <div class="left downer"><span class="font">J</span>ames</div>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `,` right after class `left`. `,` made class name `left` invalid as it read `left,`.

```
<h1 class="h1">
        <div class="left"><span class="font">H</span>ello</div>
        <div class="left down"><span class="font">T</span>here</div>
        <div class="left downer"><span class="font">J</span>ames</div>
</h1>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gt5DU/)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, you should get rid of the commas in your `class` attribute.

In newer browsers you can actually create the effect you are trying to achieve without the extra markup by using the [`:first-letter`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) pseudo element instead of wrapping the first letter in a `span` element.

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="h1">
  <div class="left">Hello</div>
  <div class="left down">There</div>
  <div class="left downer">James</div>
</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
.left:first-letter {
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qTguq/6/)</kbd> demo.